# Up to date, working Google apps-script example integrated with spreadsheet?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I'm trying to build some kind of GUI on top of/embedded into a google spreadsheet.
I've been crawling through the docs, and sadly, hitting a wall.
I DID find the sample video, at
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VmEPo6Rkq4

Unfortunately, it seems out of date and broken :( Some of the calls are no longer valid.
And, while I think I figured that part out, I cant get the callback handler to be recognized.
It gives me a runtime error of

```
"Error encountered: Script function not found: 
  function respondToSubmit(e) {
   /* full body of function here*/
}"
```

The odd thing is, for supposedly not finding it, it does a good job of printing out the whole function body.
It doesnt seem to be an error inside the function itself, because when I make it an EMPTY function, it still gives the same error :(

Could someone please point me to a simple, working example of how to add a UI alongside a google spreadsheet, or equivalent?

Please note that I dont need a general-purpose, standalone application(I think).
I'm just trying to embed some GUI type functions, in one very specific google spreadsheet that I have.

Comment: Provide ALL relevant code. Also the official google samples eork fine.

Comment: This is it! thanks!
  I guess it wasnt so ambiguous after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of simple Spreadsheet UIs using three different approaches in the 
[Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) documentation. They all work today. The third approach, Custom Dialogs, can be implemented using UiService or HtmlService, but that page only shows an example using HtmlService.

Comment: Well, yes those work great. Only trouble is those are only dialogs.
There's no example of handling callbacks.

Mogsdad's earlier post hit the issue. My experience with other languages blinded me to the actual code; Whereas other languages pass functions directly, app-script expects you to pass the function name as a STRING. Duh.